Mount CephFS error connection
I need to mount the Ceph as a file storage.
But I get an error
[root@rv31 ~]# mount -t ceph 192.168.1.88:/ /data/cephmount/ -o name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/admin.secret 
mount error 110 = Connection timed out

The firewall is turned off.
Ceph status:
[root@host1 ~]# ceph status
cluster:
  id:     28f0f54f-10a0-442a-ab10-ab68381f56e3
  health: HEALTH_WARN
        mons are allowing insecure global_id reclaim

services:
  mon: 3 daemons, quorum host1,host2,host3 (age 7h)
  mgr: host1.home.dom(active, since 7h)
  osd: 3 osds: 3 up (since 7h), 3 in (since 21h)

data:
  pools:   2 pools, 33 pgs
  objects: 905 objects, 3.4 GiB
  usage:   10 GiB used, 50 GiB / 60 GiB avail
  pgs:     33 active+clean


[root@host1 ~]# ceph orch host ls
Error ENOENT: No orchestrator configured (try `ceph orch set backend`)

Ceph.conf:
[global]
fsid = 28f0f54f-10a0-442a-ab10-ab68381f56e3
mon_initial_members = host1, host2, host3
mon_host = 192.168.1.88,192.168.1.89,192.168.1.90
auth_cluster_required = cephx
auth_service_required = cephx
auth_client_required = cephx
[mds.a]
host = host1.home.dom

Other info:
[root@host1 ceph]# systemctl status ceph-mds.target
● ceph-mds.target - ceph target allowing to start/stop all ceph- 
mds@.service instances at once
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ceph-mds.target; enabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active since Wed 2024-09-25 08:26:56 MSK; 9h ago

[root@host1 ceph]# ceph mds stat
2 up:standby




Who is 192.168.1.88? It should be one of your MON servers, not the MDS server.

192.168.1.88 - my host.
Added pictures to question

What is the ceph status?

Added status to question

Added ceph orch host ls

Your MDS service is down, it's not shown in the "services" section. You need to check why it's not up. This explains why you can't mount it.

Added info about MDS.

The mds target is only a wrapper for the mds service. You need to check your actual mds service for failures and bring it back up. It appears to be a non-cephadm cluster, then the service could be ceph-mds@{mds name}.service. Check the daemon logs as well.

I ran mds on all nodes and was able to mount the storage
